# Unable to load the following extension file: Better Workflow

Tags: better-workflow

I upgraded EE from v2.6.1 to v2.7.1. After upgrade, I am getting the following error:

> Unable to load the following extension file:
>   ext.ep_better_workflow.php[image]

Could anyone please help me.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have Better Workflow installed?

Comment: @DerekHogue Yes, I have Better Workflow installed.

Comment: The error would indicate that the extension file is missing from the Better Workflow package. Did you upgrade Better Workflow but maybe not upload all the files? I'd download the latest version and completely replace the package on the server.

Comment: @DerekHogue Thanks for your input. I resolved this issue by adding a config variable `third_party_path` like  `$config['third_party_path'] = 'path/to/third_party';`

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer and mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by adding a config variable `third_party_path` like `$config['third_party_path'] = 'path/to/third_party';`